# Advertising Accounts not found in v2/profiles

Tags: amazon-advertising-api

i am new to Amazon Advertising API. I have Advertising Access with my KDP and my MBA Account on amazon. I am also a data scientist, therefore i want to analyse my campaigns more deeply in R.

So i managed to get my accesst_token and refresh_token, but when i request 'https://advertising-api-eu.amazon.com/v2/profiles/' or 'https://advertising-api.amazon.com/v2/profiles/' i can only see my KDP profiles and two unknown advertising profiles from Germany (all with 'account type = vendor').

But i can't see my MBA Advertising Accounts from Germany, France, Spain, Italy, UK or US with its campaigns. I am doing something wrong or do i missed something in the setup?

Scope is "advertising::campaign_management.

I am thankful for any help, the offical documentation does not help much.

Comment: Did you authorize your app under these accounts that you are not seeing?

Answer (score 2):

For the Merch By Amazon Advertising Accounts you have to request "/managerAccounts" instead of "v2/profiles/"

-> https://advertising-api.amazon.com/managerAccounts

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is an existing bug within the advertising API. You may have to create a support ticket in JIRA for it to get resolved.